# How to find out why WebView is not showing content?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

There is a page every time I try to display it in a webview, nothing happens, but only on Android 4.1-4.3 (Jelly Bean). For Android version 4.4 and higger, it works.

Only that page is not working, others for example https://www.google.com work.

I use this code to setup webview. I use both clients (WebChromeClient & WebViewClient) and override all their methods to see what is going on.

```
    webView.setFocusable(true);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I also tried to this advice, but it shows nothing.
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
  public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
    Log.d("MyApplication", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                         + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                         + cm.sourceId() );
    return true;
  }
});
```

It doesn´t seems to be problem of certificates or TLS, because I can see for example contact section for this site. It seems that JavaScript is not working properly, but I can´t find out why. Is there something else I can do to track source of problem?

Comment: Can u try debugging the webview through inspect window of Chrome?

Comment: I may be wrong, but this is not working for Android 4.2.2, right?

Answer (score 0):

android Jellybean is not support TLS 1.2 (TLS 1.2 is enabled on >4.4 android version). If you want to support for 4.1-4.3 you can use GeckoView from Firefox or ChromeTabs (because, by default their web engine is support for TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2)